# Changing background image with a fade transition

Tags: javascript, background, fade, transition, rollover

I've got a very basic splash page set up for my website. Using Javascript I've set it so when the user hovers over the enter site link the body background changes. What I want to do now is add a fade transition between the changeovers (at the moment it just jumps)

this is my script below

```
<!--

var backImage = new Array(); 
backImage[0] = "splashbackground.jpg";
backImage[1] = "backgroun3.jpg";

function setBackground() { <!--sets the default background for the page//-->
  if (document.body) {
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url("splashbackground.jpg")';
 }
}
function changeBGImage(whichImage){ <!--fist background change onMouseOver event//-->
  if (document.body){
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url("backgroun3.jpg")';

}
}

function changeBGImage2(whichImage){<!-- changes background back onMouseOut event//-->
if (document.body){
document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url("splashbackground.jpg")';

}
}
```